# Quiero hacer un span que cambie de color cada que cambie el status de API, quiero utilizar un switch, hay 7 casos de uso, por cada uso un color difer

Tags: javascript, api, switch, estilos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**Quiero hacer que cambie de status de con diferentes colores por medio de una api conforme vaya cambiando de casos de uso, ya intente ejemplos de varios switch pero no me salen**

```
var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.id = 'status_'+i;
    span.className = 'status-circle-simple';
    span.textContent = ""+data[i].status;
    span.style = 'background-color: rgb(51, 105, 30);'
    section.appendChild(span)
```

**Lo ultimo que hice en JS fue esto:**
function DataCircle(){
let span = data+[i]['status'];

```
switch(circle){
    case status6:
        if(textContent = ""+data[i].status){
        status6.title = "seis";
        statusTime.style.backgroundColor = YELLOW_A700;
        break;
    }


}
```

**Mis cards son las siguientes y quiero que cambie el circulo que se ve en la esquina de la parte superior el color por default es verde pero quiero que cada que se cambie un estado de una API cambie de color y quiero utilizar un switch, son 7 diferentes casos de uso, se que lo que intente en lo ultimo no esta completo para 7 casos pero no se muy bien que poner si no me sale el primer caso de uso.

**Conexión de API**

```js
window.onload = function() {
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "http://192.168.3.45:8555/cgs/getstatus");
request.send();
request.onload = () => {
    console.log(request);
    if (request.status == 200) {
        datosFEos = JSON.parse(request.response);
        console.log(datosFEos)
        datos = datosFEos.data
        console.log(datos)
        console.log(datos[0])
        cardGenerator(datos.length, datos)
        //generar(datos)
    } else {
        console.log('error ${request.status} ${request.statusText}')
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Y cuál es el error o problema que estás teniendo? Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y leas [ask] y [example]

Comment: No hay error, quiero saber como hacer un switch con diferentes casos de uso para un span y que la respuesta se arrastre desde una API

Comment: Si no hay error entonces vuelvo a insistir en que hagas el [tour] y leas [ask] y [example]. Qué has intentado hasta el momento? No estaras esperando que programemos por ti? Gracias!

Comment: No me queda claro cual es el resultado esperado

Comment: Intente haciendo esto function DataCircle(){
    let span = data+[i]['status'];

    switch(circle){
        case status6:
            if(textContent = ""+data[i].status){
            status6.title = "seis";
            statusTime.style.backgroundColor = YELLOW_A700;
            break;
        }


    }

Comment: Por favor agrega el ejemplo en tu pregunta, no en los comentarios. Haz click en [edit] para editarla

Comment: Gracias! Ahora lo que no entiendo es qué es exactamente lo que quieres hacer. Cuando dices "ya intente ejemplos de varios switch pero no me salen" qué debería pasar? Una buena forma de ayudarnos a entender se encuentra aqui -> [example]

Comment: Agregue un extra para ver si se entiende un poco mas mi problema

Comment: Bien, ahora entiendo un poco más. Los círculos verdes deberían cambiar de color en base a la respuesta de una API. Cómo te comunicas con esa API? O bien, a qué te refieres con API?

Comment: Si, la api la tengo conectada, dejo la conexión arriba

Comment: Por lo que veo, el código que cambia de color el span debería ir dentro del `request.onload = () => {}` ya que ahí es donde tienes la respuesta de la API. Ahora bien, con respecto al switch que mencionas, cuáles son los posibles Status que devuelve tu API?

Comment: Mis posibles resultados son Esperando, Maquina corriendo, maquina no esta pasando piezas, maquina detenida, modo manual abierto, maquina apagada, opcion 1.

Comment: Creas una clase CSS por cada estado, en esa clase colocas el color adecuado, digamos que le llamas ".estado1", ".estado2", etc. Luego esta línea `span.className = 'status-circle-simple';` la cambias por `span.className = 'status-circle-simple estado' + data[i].status;`

Comment: Muchas gracias, estoy a punto de resolverlo